# Unable to install Windows Identity Foundation on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wif

I have been trying to install Windows Identity Foundation for last 4 hours on Windows 7 and everything I tried did not result in successful installation. I tried searching in Google and nothing helped me so far. I had .NET 4.5 and uninstalling it did not help. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Do you want to install WIF 3.5 or 4.5?

Comment: Notice that **Visual Studio 2013 installation fails to complete setup** because it cannot install **Windows Identity Foundation** (included in `"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\453CF16FEC3A0A6674313660D783F323C6844858\packages\sptoolsDependencies\Windows6.1-KB974405-x64.msu"`). It says `"Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSU package"` and `"Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package"`. I have tried to install it separately but that fails as well. As result, two features of the setup cannot be installed: Silverlight + Office components.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install WIF anymore, it's included in the .NET 4.5 core by default, in the System.IdentityModel namespace.

> The first version of Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) shipped as a standalone download and is known as WIF 3.5 because it was introduced in the .NET 3.5 SP1 timeframe. Starting with .NET 4.5, WIF is part of the .NET framework.

You can find the list of new namespaces [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157091.aspx) if you're migrating from .NET 3.5/4.0, just reference those and you're good to go!

Comment: See my comment on the question - yes it is required, it is part of Visual Studio 2013 setup. If it fails, then Visual Studio installation fails as well.